# Prepend will not add HTML within img tag

Tags: jquery, html, forms

This is my jquery code....

```
$("#addinp").click(function() {
    $(this).prepend('<label>Item ' + i + '<span class="small"></label><input type="text" name="middlename[]" />');
});
```

And this is my html....

```
<form id="form" name="form" method="post" action="?a=run">
<input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" />
<input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" />
<input type="text" name="middlename[]" id="middlename[]" />
<img src="add_another_name.png"  id="addinp"/>
<button type="submit">Add</button>
 </form>
```

This will not make another input appear before the "add another button" - The annoying this is if i do this...

```
 $('form').prepend('<lab........
```

prepend it to the form it will work....... but the it will just not appear before the image...

Comment: You are prepending invalid HTML.

Comment: I would suggest that `<label>Item '+i+'<span class="small"></label>` should be `<label class="small">Item '+i+'</label>`

Comment: That's true, but not the cause of the problem.

Comment: The label should either have a for attribute matching the id of the input, or should contain the input. As it stands, it is useless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `prepend()`, try [`before()`](http://api.jquery.com/before/) as in the following, with valid HTML.

`prepend()` will not work here because it inserts the passed element as a child of it at the beginning of target.

```
$("#addinp").click(function() {
    $(this)
     .before('<label>Item '+i+'<span class="small"></span></label><input type="text" name="middlename[]" />');
});
```

You can also use [`.insertBefore()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/):

```
$("#addinp").click(function() {
   $('<label>Item '+i+'<span class="small"></span></label><input type="text" name="middlename[]" />').insertBefore(this);
});
```

***Don't forget to correct your above HTML.***

Answer (score 2):

From [the manual](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/):

> The .prepend() method inserts the specified content as the first child of each element in the jQuery collection

You can't insert content as the first child of an image because the image can't have children.

You want [`before()`](http://api.jquery.com/before/) to insert the content before the image.